# Support Library for Chronometer in Android

Tags: android, android-support-library, chronometer

If there any support Library function that could make the `setCountDown` function of the chronometer support by APIs lower than 24?

Comment: How about copy-pasting sources of API 24 into your project and using that `Chronometer` instead?

Comment: can you elaborate ?

Comment: What about copy pasting [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/Chronometer.java) class into your package and use `com.your.package.Chronometer` class instead of `android.widget.Chronometer`.

Comment: tried but didn't work

Comment: `tried but didn't work` What exactly didn't work?

Comment: You also have to copy the string resources. They're in <sdk>/platforms/android-XX/data/res/values and values-YY based on language you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Android Documentation , its not possible with below API level 24. [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) widget only use count up. If you need to do so go with [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

For Example:

```
final int oneSecond = 1000; // in milliSeconds i.e. 1 second
final int tenSeconds = 100000; // 100 seconds
CountDownTimer cTimer =  new CountDownTimer(100000, oneSecond) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

             int totalTime = 60000; // in milliseconds i.e. 60 seconds
             String v = String.format("%02d", millisUntilFinished/totalTime);
             int va = (int)( (millisUntilFinished%totalTime)/oneSecond);
             textView.setText("remaining seconds: " +v+":"+String.format("%02d",va));
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         textView.setText("done!");
     }
  };
  cTimer.start();
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to go with GitHub Solution then have a look at [this](https://github.com/CardinalNow/Android-CountdownTimer) and [this](https://github.com/iwgang/CountdownView)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [RXJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) to simple handle threads, timers, and many other functionalities.

The documentation for the timer operator says this:

> Create an Observable that emits a particular item after a given delay

Thus the behavior you are observing is expected- timer() emits just a single item after a delay.

The interval operator, on the other hand, will emit items spaced out with a given interval.

For example, this Observable will emit an item every second:

> Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

And an complete example:

```
Observable.interval(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
        .take(300) // take 300 second
        .map(v -> 300 - v)
        .subscribe(
            onNext -> {
                //on every second pass trigger
            },
            onError -> {
                //do on error
            },
            () -> {
                //do on complete
            },
            onSubscribe -> {
                //do once on subscription
            });
```